# How to config kamailio core dump file path?

Tags: kamailio

By default, the core file is dumped in '/' directory. But this isn't ideal in our set up.
How do I configure the path of the core file generated? Can it be done in kamailio.cfg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the path to the directory via **workdir** global parameter in kamailio.cfg or via **-w** command line parameter to kamailio.

```
workdir=/tmp/kamailio
```

or

```
/usr/sbin/kamailio -w /tmp/kamailio ...
```

Comment: It's right in the core cookbook. I'm surprised google didn't find it for me. Thanks.